# What is the difference try catch and building a function?

Tags: php, try-catch

I want to know what is the performance which will be added to my code if i use `try catch` method instead of building a `functions`, to be more clearly here is a comparison:

**Function method:**

```html
<?php 
       $num_1 = 5;
       $num_2 = 12;
       compare($num_1, $num_2);
  

function compare($var1, $var2){
  if ($var2 > $var1) echo "That's Right 12 is bigger than 5";
  if ($var2 < $var1) echo "That's Wrong 12 is Not less than 5";
  exit();
  }
  
  ?>
```

***Try Catch method:***

```html
<?php 
       $num_1 = 5;
       $num_2 = 12;
       
  try{
    if ($var2 > $var1) throw new Exception("That's Right 12 is bigger than 5");
    if ($var2 < $var1) throw new Exception("That's Wrong 12 is Not less than 5");
    }
         
  catch (Exception $e) {
      echo "$e->getMessage()";
      exit();
   }
  ?>
```

in these two method i will get the same result, so what is the benefit of using `try catch` and when i decide i must use it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `try...catch` for returning values? It is not meant to do that.

Try...catch is meant to catch exceptions, like a zero divide, writing a read only file, things like that, not to return values.

For using try...catch on a function, use something like this:

```
<?php
function divide($first, $second) {
    try {
        $result = $first / $second;
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        die("Error. Division by zero");
    }
    return $result;
}
?>
```

Comment: Please could you go in more details and support the answer with code examples.

Comment: Your first code makes sense, it's fine. The second code works, but don't use try...catch for that. I added an example on my question.

Comment: @mohamedmaher It would make more sense to just read a tutorial on exceptions and try...catch. They have a very specific purpose.